# How to crop a widget

Tags: flutter

I've got a child with a set size. However, I want to be able to dynamically crop the widget (say cut it 50% horizontally aka display only the left half). Is there an easy way of doing this without external libs?

I can only think of using a Stack with overflow hidden...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use [`ClipRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html):

> A widget that clips its child using a rectangle.
> By default, ClipRect prevents its child from painting outside its bounds, but the size and location of the clip rect can be customized using a custom clipper.

The following example crops an `Image` horizontally by half:

```
ClipRect(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    widthFactor: 0.5,
    child: Image.network(userAvatarUrl),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, why do I need the align?

Comment: Happy to help! The `Image` is wrapped in an `Align` `Widget` to position it inside the clipper and the `widthFactor` is used to define the size of the clipper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of cropping a widget using `Stack`

```dart
class WidgetCrop extends StatelessWidget {
  final Rect cropRect;
  final Widget child;

  const WidgetCrop({super.key, required this.cropRect, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: cropRect.size.aspectRatio,
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        final scaleFactor = (constraints.smallest.width / cropRect.size.width);

        return Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: -cropRect.top,
              left: -cropRect.left,
              child: Transform.scale(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                scale: scaleFactor,
                origin: cropRect.topLeft,
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```